# my html and css file is opening in binary form in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext

[HTML file opening in binary form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkJBf.png)

This file is from mac and my laptop is windows i have tried change the file name but nothing happen

Comment: That doesn't look like an HTML file, are you sure you are opening the correct file?

Comment: yes i have downloaded from my course video web designing that file and that was html file and it was written and i know it showing binary in sublime text then i also converted it to html nothing happen

Comment: Don't open files in folders titled [`__MACOSX`](https://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder). They are binary system files called resource forks from, you guessed it, macOS, and aren't intended to be interacted with by users. Look around for a file named `index.html` (no leading `._`) in the ZIP file you received, or however you got the course material. If in doubt, ask your instructor.

Answer (score 1):

As @MattDMo commented - it's a binary system file from macOS not an HTML file.

I write a copy of your data to a file in python

```py
hexData = ' '.join((
    '00 05 16 07 00 02 00 00 4d 61 63 20 4f 53 20 58',
    '20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 02 00 00 00 09 00 00',
    '00 32 00 00 00 a2 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 d4 00 00',
    '00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00',
    '00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00',
    '00 00 00 00 41 54 54 52 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d4',
    '00 00 00 98 00 00 00 3c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00',
    '00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 98 00 00 00 3c',
    '00 00 15 63 6f 6d 2e 61 70 70 6c 65 2e 71 75 61',
    '72 61 6e 74 69 6e 65 00 71 2f 30 30 38 31 3b 35',
    '65 35 61 65 36 31 36 3b 43 68 72 6f 6d 65 3b 35',
    '41 39 32 41 38 31 46 2d 46 30 36 36 2d 34 46 35',
    '35 2d 42 32 45 36 2d 35 41 31 38 34 42 36 37 35',
    '33 34 35 00'
))
with open('test', 'wb') as outputFile:
    for byte in hexData.split(' '):
        outputFile.write(binascii.unhexlify(byte))
```

Then do `file ./test` in bash and the result is: `test: AppleDouble encoded Macintosh file`

Translated into text, it looks like this:

```
........Mac OS X        .........2......
........................................
....ATTR...............<................
.......<...com.apple.quarantine.q/0081;5
e5ae616;Chrome;5A92A81F-F066-4F55-B2E6-5
A184B675345.
```

Comment: Props for transcribing that entire file!